# Extract value from scala collect case

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I have the following code which reads data from a key/value data storage.
At some stage I want to go through everything in the storage and check expiry times and remove values - as done in the code below.

My problem here is that `dataMapStorage.get(key)` is called twice for keys which pass the filter and this can potentially be a heavy operation (I/O).

```
dataMapStorage.keys
  .filter { key =>
    val value = dataMapStorage.get(key)
    currentTime.getMillis - value.getMillis > timeout
  }
  .foreach { key =>
    val value = dataMapStorage.get(key) // Want to avid this double lookup
    // ... do some work with "value"
    dataMapStorage.remove(key)
  }
```

I presume the way around it is using `collect` (I do not want to map through the storage and extract all the values as this might be large), but am stuck here too with the 'get' method:

```
dataMapStorage.keys
  .collect { 
    case key if {
      val value = dataMapStorage.get(key)
      currentTime.getMillis - value.getMillis > timeout
    } => (key, value) // How can I get the "value"???
  }
  .foreach { pair =>
    val value = pair._2
    // ... do some work with "value"
    dataMapStorage.remove(pair._1)
  }
```

How can I run this code getting the value from storage only once and **not** first creating a list of all the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `filter` isn't actually producing any benefit if the resulting collection isn't saved for further processing.

```
dataMapStorage.keys
  .foreach { key =>
    val value = dataMapStorage.get(key)
    if (currentTime.getMillis - value.getMillis > timeout) {
      // ... do some work with "value"
      dataMapStorage.remove(key)
    }
  }
```

Also, if `dataMapStorage` is just a key->value `Map` then couldn't you simplify it?

```
dataMapStorage.foreach { case (key, value) =>
    if (currentTime.getMillis - value.getMillis > timeout) {
      // ... do some work with "value"
      dataMapStorage.remove(key)
    }
  }
```

You could use `collect()` here but since the procedure results in a side-effect I think `foreach()` is more explanatory.

Of course the *real* Scala FP approach is to avoid mutable data structures.

```
val newDataMapStorage = oldDataMapStorage.filter { case (key, value) =>
    if (currentTime.getMillis - value.getMillis > timeout) {
      // ... do some work with "value"
      false
    } else true
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move `// ... do some work with "value"` into `filter`, so that in `foreach` you just remove the `key`.

Comment: I only want to do the work on the filtered values before removing them. I guess I could add an `if` there but thought there would be a more scala-way of doing it?